# CSS3 change button background colour left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm just having a little fun with CSS3 transitions and was thinking how would I animation a button to be filled in with a different colour when you hover over? So for example

We have a button which is white, when someone hovers over the button the button will fill up with blue from the left side to the right side, and when they stop hovering over the button the button will fill up in white from the right side to the left side, does anyone have any ideas on how this is done? The only website I can see a clear is the [Pokémon](http://www.pokemon.com/uk/) website.

Comment: CSS gradients and background-position - now off to google you go! :)

Comment: This has helped a little, but I still can't get the result I would like, nevermind I will post my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is all the css you need to achieve the simple effect

```
.wrapper .navigation button
{
    width: 150;
    height: 85;
    background: linear-gradient(red 50%, blue 50%);
    transition: background 1s ease-out;
    background-size:1px 170px; 
}

.wrapper .navigation button:hover
{
    background-position:0px 85px; 
}
```

Comment: This effect makes a sharp line between the red half and the blue half, to make it blur (smooth transition between the two colors), you can try tweaking it a little like this http://jsfiddle.net/LzUaC/6/